# Unable to output actual json data inside javascript script tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Am trying to output actual json data inside javascript tag dynamically using ajax and php but this is not working anymore meanwhile json data is getting as desired. Actully when I test returned result json data from php script using console.log(response), It prints correct data in firebug console. I also have used `JSON.parse(response)` and also tried `JSON.stringify(response)` but nothing is working and not outputting (printing) in javascript script tag if we assign the data using`stackevents: response` and when I see the page source code it displays only `stackevents: response` but not actual output like this below one

```
stackevents:[{"date":"2013-08-24","type":"arrowDown","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"417","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-25","type":"pin","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"417","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-26","type":"sign","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"531","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-27","type":"arrowUp","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#00CC00","value":"333","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-28","type":"pin","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF","value":"552","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-29","type":"arrowUp","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"492","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-30","type":"pin","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF","value":"379","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-31","type":"pin","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"767","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-09-01","type":"flag","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"169","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-09-02","type":"arrowUp","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"314","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-09-03","type":"arrowDown","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"437","description":"This is description of an event"}]
```

For more clarification, I want like this

```
stackevents:[{"date":"2013-08-24","type":"arrowDown","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"417","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-25","type":"pin","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"417","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-26","type":"sign","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"531","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-27","type":"arrowUp","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#00CC00","value":"333","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-28","type":"pin","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF","value":"552","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-29","type":"arrowUp","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"492","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-30","type":"pin","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#FFFFFF","value":"379","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-08-31","type":"pin","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"767","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-09-01","type":"flag","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"169","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-09-02","type":"arrowUp","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"314","description":"This is description of an event"},{"date":"2013-09-03","type":"arrowDown","graph":"g1","backgroundColor":"#85CDE6","value":"437","description":"This is description of an event"}]
```

in place of `stackevents: response` using javascript, jquery, ajax and php.

Thank You.

Comment: Please provide code used to try to print this to the script tag

Comment: Have you checked the with console.log(response.jsondata) to see whether you are getting the data over there.

Comment: amarjit singh yes I have checked using console.log. It printing correctly in firebug console and also giving correct output when using alert. But not inside script tag

Answer (score 0):

If you have to call the .php to GET the json data and you want to write that to the script tag of the page, here is an example: https://codepen.io/mix3d/pen/qQNZWQ
I do not cover using PHP to insert the json data into the html as the page is being rendered.

Simply include `<script type="application/json" id="myscript"></script>` in your html somewhere, and then with the following code, you can accept JSON data from your .php file and insert it into the script tag using innerHTML. Because a script tag is just another DOM element, you can access them with JS just like a `div` or `button`.

```
fetch('https://path-to.your/file.php')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json)
    document.getElementById('myscript').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json,null,2);
})
```

`JSON.stringify()`'s 2nd and 3rd parameters are to prettyprint the JSON object into your script tag. If you do not stringify the object first, you will get `[object Object]` as the content of your script tag, as JS will use type-coercion to get the string of the object.

If the above code using modern JS's fetch is too much, here is an example using jQuery as well:

```
$.getJSON( "https://path-to.your/file.php", function( json ) {
    document.getElementById('myscript').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json,null,2);
})
```

Furthermore, if you wanted to go so far as to CREATE the script tag to put the JSON into:

```
let jsonScript = document.createElement('script');
// if you don't set the type, the browser will try to execute the text as JS instead of JSON.
jsonScript.setAttribute('type', 'application/json');
jsonScript.textContent = JSON.stringify(json);
document.head.appendChild(jsonScript); // or document.body, your choice
```

You will have to JSON.parse the script content to get any useful data from it though!

Comment: Still not sure why you are trying to do this, however.